# Using PointerOver style on Button requires double-tapping from a touch device (mouse clicking is fine)

Tags: c#, hover, windows-store-apps, imagebutton, visualstatemanager

I'm writing Windows Store app using C#/VS2013

When I modify a button image style to create an effect when the mouse pointer is over the button, I use the following:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Image Source="/button_enabled.png" x:Name="Image" Height="50" >
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="/button_enabled.png"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="/button_over.png"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                           <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="/button_click.png"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Image>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This works perfectly fine when I'm using a mouse to navigate the cursor.

However, when I use the touch screen to tap the button (instead of using a mouse to click the button), it ALWAYS requires 2 separate clicks to register an action.

If I remove the PointerOver section, then everything works fine (both mouse clicking and  touching/tapping), but I lose the mouse-over effect when using a mouse.

Anyone has ideas on why this is happening?  Is this a bug in the PointerOver attribute?

**Update**
This is how the buttons are instantiated:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1">
      <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Tag="Style1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0" Click="Btn_Click" PointerReleased="Btn_Released" IsEnabled="True"/>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: First thing I'd probably do is wrap the Image in a Grid, then put the VisualStates inside the Grid instead of directly in the Image. I bet there is an issue happening with the Focused states. The first tap is focusing the button, the second tap is activating it (is my guess).

Comment: @NateDiamond First-tap activates and second-tap clicks is my guess too, but I can't figure out how to avoid this behavior.  The button is already wrapped inside its own Grid.  What do you mean by "put the VisualStates inside the Grid"?

Comment: So right now you have `<ControlTemplate><Image><VisualStates/></Image></ControlTemplate>`. I'm suggesting `<ControlTemplate><Grid><Image/><VisualStates/></Grid></ControlTemplate>`.

Comment: @NateDiamond unfortunately wrapping it up in <Grid> rendered the entire ControlTemplate non-functional.  There are no PointerOver/Pressed effects anymore.

Comment: Did you move the `VisualState` definition outside of the `Image` tags? Or leave them in?

Comment: After your update, is the use of `ButtonStyle` versus `ButtonStyle1` a typo?

Comment: Hi @NateDiamond I left VisualState inside the `Image` tags.  Should I have taken it out?  `ButtonStyle` is actually a generic name I put up here, since the actual style name contains our company name/project name.  It is matching in the real code.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. If you note the Xaml I posted, the `VisualState` tag is outside of the Image tag. (Note the `/`).